# impala-start-cluster fails to start

Tags: impala, dlopen

I have build the latest impala from source. I have done something similar to this

```
time git clone https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf/impala.git ~/Impala
cd Impala
export IMPALA_HOME=`pwd`
export IMPALA_BUILD_THREADS=20
time $IMPALA_HOME/bin/bootstrap_build.sh 
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/apache-impala/bin
source bin/impala-config.sh
bin/start-impala-cluster.py
```

It fails to start saying

```
$ $IMPALA_HOME/bin/start-impala-cluster.py
12:51:37 MainThread: Found 0 impalad/0 statestored/0 catalogd process(es)
12:51:37 MainThread: Starting State Store logging to /opt/Impala/logs/cluster/statestored.INFO
12:51:37 MainThread: Starting Catalog Service logging to /opt/Impala/logs/cluster/catalogd.INFO
12:51:37 MainThread: Starting Impala Daemon logging to /opt/Impala/logs/cluster/impalad.INFO
12:51:37 MainThread: Starting Impala Daemon logging to /opt/Impala/logs/cluster/impalad_node1.INFO
12:51:37 MainThread: Starting Impala Daemon logging to /opt/Impala/logs/cluster/impalad_node2.INFO
12:51:40 MainThread: Found 0 impalad/0 statestored/0 catalogd process(es)
12:51:42 MainThread: Found 0 impalad/0 statestored/0 catalogd process(es)
12:51:43 MainThread: Found 0 impalad/0 statestored/0 catalogd process(es)
12:51:44 MainThread: Found 0 impalad/0 statestored/0 catalogd process(es)
12:51:45 MainThread: Found 0 impalad/0 statestored/0 catalogd process(es)
12:51:46 MainThread: Found 0 impalad/0 statestored/0 catalogd process(es)
12:51:47 MainThread: Found 0 impalad/0 statestored/0 catalogd process(es)
12:51:48 MainThread: Found 0 impalad/0 statestored/0 catalogd process(es)
12:51:49 MainThread: Found 0 impalad/0 statestored/0 catalogd process(es)
12:51:50 MainThread: Found 0 impalad/0 statestored/0 catalogd process(es)
12:51:51 MainThread: Found 0 impalad/0 statestored/0 catalogd process(es)
12:51:51 MainThread: Error starting cluster
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/Impala/bin/start-impala-cluster.py", line 770, in <module>
    expected_cluster_size - expected_catalog_delays)
  File "/opt/Impala/tests/common/impala_cluster.py", line 166, in wait_until_ready
    self.wait_for_num_impalads(expected_num_impalads)
  File "/opt/Impala/tests/common/impala_cluster.py", line 212, in wait_for_num_impalads
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: Expected 3 impalad(s), only 0 found
statestored failed to start.
catalogd failed to start.
```

In the logs I have

```
$ cat logs/cluster/impalad_node1-out.log 
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
F0219 12:51:38.087685 35437 unwind_safeness.cc:76] Check failed: !error failed to find symbol dlopen: /opt/Impala/be/build/debug/kudu_util/libkudu_util.so: undefined symbol: dlopen
```

I get that for all log files.

I am on a newly installed ubuntu 18.04 server.

Do you have any suggestion on how to debug?

Relevant links? a solution?

Anything else, that might help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect that I had a build error, that has now been rectified. Closing this

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that I had a build error, that has now been rectified. Closing this